# Ionic ModalPage content hides on scroll, not sure why

Tags: typescript, user-interface, ionic-framework, scroll

I have multiple Modal pages which are opened using the `ModalController`, but one in particular is showing strange behavior. This modal is opened when the user clicks/taps a list-item (which is a list of users) then the ModalPage shows all badges the clicked user has. The data is loaded from within the `ionViewWillEnter` function.

When I click a user for the first time and the modal opens I'm able to scroll. But when I close the modal, click that user again and then scroll on the page all the content gets hidden. When I first open another page, then go back to the users page and click any user to open the modal page it works again. But then, just as before when I close the modal and reopen it for that user the content hides on scroll.

The user (object) is passed by as a NavParam.

Anyone familiar with this behavior?

My typescript file (where myApi is injected in my constructor and also defined as an import):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-modal-user-badges',
    templateUrl: 'modal-user-badges.html',
})
export class ModalUserBadgesPage {
    user: any;
    badges: any;
    badgeCount: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
        this.user = this.navParams.get('user');
    }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.myApi.getBadgesForUser(this.user.id).subscribe((response) => {
            this.badges = response;
            this.badgeCount = this.badges.length;
        });
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ModalUserBadgesPage');
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share code involved into this behavior?

Comment: "The data is loaded from within the ionViewWillEnter function." - do you mean ionViewWillEnter for a modal? also unclear what do you mean by "hidden content"?

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: So whats up with hiding? What dies that mean? Content is not shown or?

Comment: Found the issue, it was caused in relation with animate.css which performs an animation on several elements on the page. The hiding/removal occured when the data was not fully retrieved. I've disabled animations on the page, as they were a bit overwhelming anyway. Now it's working like it should. Thanks for reaching out and thinking with me!